# Jquery mobile Pageshow - delete previous data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile web-app and I want to fill a div-list on pageshow with some information.

```
$('#data').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) { 
    $("#facInfoList").html("some data...."); 
}
```

Before I fill this list, I want to delete the hole content of the page, because If it is the second call, there are still datas in the list from the first call.
(Set to the defaults, like this is the first call of the page)

I try it with $("#facInfoList").html(""); but this doesn´t work on every browser.

I want to restore the page at the first step and then fill the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just you make the list empty

```
 $('#data').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) { 
   $("#facInfoList").empty(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#facInfoList").empty()` instead ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)), that should do the trick.

Please note that `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, you should use `.on()` if you're on one of the latest jQuery (see [`.live()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/live/))